# Splicing an Array/Effect on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array variable in $scope that I'm using to create tabs on the front end. I'm having trouble implementing a remove tab function. I'm using AngularJS/bootstrap.
This is the code for removing tabs:

```
var removeTab = function (index) {
    $scope.tabs.splice(index, 1);
};
```

This is the code I have for creating the tabs:

```
 <tabset class="tab-container">
    <tab id = "tabContent" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active" ng-select="select"> <!-- the tab highlight directive -->
      <tab-heading>
      <span>{{tab.title}}</span>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="removeTab($index)"></i> <!-- the tab close button -->
    </tab-heading>

    <textarea ui-codemirror= "{ onLoad : codemirrorLoaded }"></textarea>

  </tab>
```

When I open multiple tabs and then try closing one using the removeTab button I created, all the tabs close. The weird part is that the console clears itself as well. I'm not completely sure what's happening.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: shouldn't it say `$scope.removeTab = function(index) ....`

Comment: seems your code work: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lfkjzTkbG9Uv1TZlvHoY?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just modified your code a little to get the visuals on. So the difference was

```
//Your function 
var removeTab = function(index){
   $scope.tabs.splice(index,1);
}
__________
//changed it to
$scope.removeTab = function(index){
   $scope.tabs.splice(index,1);
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module('tabco',[]);

app.controller('TabCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.tabs = [{value:1},{value:2},{value:3},{value:4}];
  $scope.removeTab = function(index){
    $scope.tabs.splice(index,1);
  }
}]);
```

```css
.tabcont{
border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
   <div ng-app="tabco" class="tab-container"  ng-controller="TabCtrl">
    <div class="tabcont" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" > <!-- the tab highlight directive -->
      <div>
        <span>{{tab.value}}</span>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="removeTab($index)">X</i> <!-- the tab close button -->
      </div>

    <textarea></textarea>

    </div>
   </div>
```